# Tomcat 7 : authentication with multiple UserDatabaseRealms for multiple webapps

Tags: authentication, tomcat

On the same server, I need to deploy two versions of the same webapp (one for production and another for validation).

These two webapps use authentication with different databases.
I am struggling with the implementation of two different context for the two apps.

I have implemented the following code in *server.xml* but the authentication doesn't work anymore :

```
        <Context path="http://localhost:8080/myapp1" docBase="/path/webapps/myapp1.war" debug="0" privileged="true">

          <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
              /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
              /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
          <!--
          <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
          -->

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
            resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
            that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
            available for use by the Realm.  -->
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
                driverName="org.postgresql.Driver" digest="MD5"
                connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres_prod?user=postgres&amp;password=postgres"
                userTable="utilisateurs" userNameCol="login" userCredCol="password"
                userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>


            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>
    </Context>

    <Context path="http://localhost:8080/myapp2" docBase="/path/webapps/myapp2.war" debug="0" privileged="true">

          <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
              /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
              /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
          <!--
          <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
          -->

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
            resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
            that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
            available for use by the Realm.  -->
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
                driverName="org.postgresql.Driver" digest="MD5"
                connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres_val?user=postgres&amp;password=postgres"
                userTable="utilisateurs" userNameCol="login" userCredCol="password"
                userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>


            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>
    </Context>
```

I don't understand if I need to change something else in *web.xml* or *tomcat-users.xml*.
The authentication work when I test it with just one app (when I don't need a *context* tag).

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I moved the content of the two *Context* tags in the *context.xml* file of the two applications.
Another resolved problem : With this part of the code in the *server.xml* I was not able to login as the tomcat manager.